# Keypad is hiding UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

I have 10 UITextField' that are taking the whole screen. When I want to change them, I get the keypad on half a screen, so, I can't change the 'hidden' fields.
Did anyone know the solution?

Comment: you can have a scroll view for your text field, keyboard will appear whenever you click on the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the frame moved up upon the keyboard being called.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0,-[size of keyboard],self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[i have taken from here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/32204-moving-uitextfield-when-keyboard-pops-up.html):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField { 
    if (textField == textField1) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        textfield1.frame = CGRectMake(textfield1.frame.origin.x, (textfield1.frame.origin.y - 100.0), textfield1.frame.size.width, textfield1.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else if (textField == textField2) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        textfield2.frame = CGRectMake(textfield2.frame.origin.x, (textfield2.frame.origin.y - 100.0), textfield2.frame.size.width, textfield2.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {   
    if (textField == textField1) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        textfield1.frame = CGRectMake(textfield1.frame.origin.x, (textfield1.frame.origin.y + 100.0), textfield1.frame.size.width, textfield1.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else if (textField == textField2) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        textfield2.frame = CGRectMake(textfield2.frame.origin.x, (textfield2.frame.origin.y + 100.0), textfield2.frame.size.width, textfield2.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

and on touch:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{
    [textfield resignFirstResponder];
}

hope will help u.
happy to help.